# Create model instance from dict containing different keys compared to model attributes in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create model/s from an api response. The response received has different keys as compared to the model attributes in our system. I would like to know the best way to create a model from that response.

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    external_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save_to_db_from_external_data(response_data):
        map_dict = {
            'externalId': 'external_id',
            'startDate': 'start_date',
            'endDate': 'end_date'
        }
        
        if type(response_data) == 'dict':
            new_model_data_dict = {}
            for key in map_dict:
                if key in response_data:
                    new_model_data_dict[map_dict[key]] = response_data[key]
            MyModel.objects.create(**new_model_data_dict)

        elif type(response_data) == 'list':
            new_model_data_list = []
            for data_dict in response_data:
                new_data_dict = {}
                for key in map_dict:
                    if key in data_dict:
                        new_data_dict[map_dict[key]] = data_dict[key]
                new_model_data_list.append(new_data_dict)
            MyModel.objects.create(**(model_data_dict) for model_data_dict in new_model_data_list)
```

The above is the code that I have written. Is this the correct way to do the required task? Or is there any better way in django to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks fine.

Tip:
avoid to copy and paste code pieces. Try to use functions and classes wherever you can.

```py
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    external_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def create_object_from_external_data(response_data):
        MyModel.objects.create(
            external_id=response_data.get('externalId'),
            start_date=response_data.get('startDate'),
            end_date=response_data.get('endDate')
        )

    def save_to_db_from_external_data(response_data):
        if type(response_data) == 'dict':
            self.create_object_from_external_data(response_data)
        elif type(response_data) == 'list':
            for data_dict in response_data:
                self.create_object_from_external_data(data_dict)
```